# Simple question about average value of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a simple question, but I am having a moment of confusion. Assume $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ is continuous in both of its arguments and any other nice properties you would like.

Suppose one wants to evaluate $\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_0^Tf(t,a)dt}{T}$ for a fixed value of $a$. Because we are taking the limit of the average value of $f(\cdot,a)$ on $[0,T]$ as $T\rightarrow 0$, the limit must be $f(0,a)$.

Consider a slightly different exercise. Suppose we wish to evaluate $\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_0^Tf(t,T)dt}{T}$. That is, instead of a fixed value for the second argument of $f$, the second argument also varies. Does this converge to $f(0,0)$?

Answer (score 0):

The continuity in the second component implies, that for all $t\in [a,b]$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta(t,\epsilon)>0$ such that: if $|T_1 - T_2| < \delta(t,\epsilon)$, then $|f(t,T_1)-f(t,T_2)| <\epsilon$.
Now, observe that

\begin{align}
\bigg| \lim_{T\searrow 0} \frac{\int_0^T f(t,T) dt}{T}  -  \lim_{T\to 0} \frac{\int_0^T f(t,0) dt}{T} \bigg | 
&= \lim_{T\searrow 0,\atop|T|\leq \delta(t,\epsilon)}\bigg| \frac{\int_0^T f(t,T)-f(t,0) dt}{T} \bigg|\\
&\leq \lim_{T\searrow 0,\atop|T|\leq \delta(t,\epsilon)}\frac{\int_0^T  |f(t,T)-f(t,0)| dt}{T}\\
&\leq \lim_{T\searrow 0,\atop|T|\leq \delta(t,\epsilon)} \frac{\int_0^T \epsilon dt}{T} \\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align}
Choosing $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily small, we have proven
\begin{align} \lim_{T\searrow 0} \frac{\int_0^T f(t,T) dt}{T}  =  \lim_{T\to 0} \frac{\int_0^T f(t,0) dt}{T} .\end{align}
Therefore, it doesn't make any difference if the second argument varies.